# Amazon sqs throwing exception connection reset

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using **AmazonSQSAsyncClient** to connect with Amazon SQS, but sometimes I see the following execution in the logs:

```
INFO  [AmazonHttpClient:444] Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:755)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:380)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:229)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2169)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:468)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.getQueueUrl(AmazonSQSClient.java:1476)
```

I am using the **AmazonSQSAsyncClient** through out the application as singleton.

Code snippet is below.

```
static{
        if(sqsObj == null){
        sqsObj = new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("app.properties"));
        sqsObj.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.valueOf("sample region"));
    }
}
```

By using sqsobj, I am doing operations like create queue, send message and receive messages. It works fine but some time throws the exception as above. After restarting the application it works fine for sometime.

I am using aws-java-sdk-1.7.1.
Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

The "connection reset" means that the other party (i.e. the server) closed the connection.

Internally the SDK builds and reuses a http connection to not have to open a connection every time you make a request.

The log message tells you that the connection was reset, but normally this is not something to worry about. The SDK will retry automatically in cases like this. So if you are only seeing this sporadically in the logs but everything works as expected you should probably not worry about it